# How do you change position of UIView when scrolling a UITableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

i have a uiview and i want to hide and show when you scroll down and up the tableview,

This is what i have done so far:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if ([scrollView.panGestureRecognizer translationInView:scrollView.superview].y > 0) {
        NSLog(@"moving up");
    } else {
        scrollingUp = false;
        NSLog(@"moving down");
        [self pushUpsearchView];
    }
}
```

pushUpsearchView method:

```
-(void)pushUpsearchView{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        CGRect frame = self.mysearchView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.mysearchView.frame.origin.x;
        frame.origin.y =   100;
        self.mysearchView.frame = frame;
        self.mysearchView.frame = frame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        NSLog(@"Finished animating!");
    }];
}
```

But this is what i end up with:

[image: For some weird reason it duplicates it!]

However when i remove `[self pushUpsearchView]` from the `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` method, and put it in my `viewdidload` method, it works just fine without duplicating it it simply changes its position

Comment: It looks like you're somehow creating two instances of that search view. It's the only way you could possibly see two of them.

Comment: haha thanks ! just realised in my viewdidload method, i added my searchview twice